# Saxon line break issue in output XML

Tags: xslt, saxon

I am using Saxon HE 9.5 as my XSLT processor. Since the source is a large-sized XML, I need to minimize the size of output. However, using the Saxon HE will add line breaks between each element tags. Such as the following example:

```
 <Element1>
   <attr1>
    test1
   </attr1>
 </Element1>
```

I want it to be like:

```
<Element1> <attr1> test1 </attr1> </Element1>
```

so that I can minimize the size of the output XML. Is there any way to do it?
I have tried to set indent="no", but the output XML is failed to open.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<xsl:output indent="no"/>` to turn off the indenting, but your line breaks in elements that contain text will still be there (even with `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`). You can use `normalize-space()` to remove them.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<Element1>
    <attr1>
        test1
    </attr1>
</Element1>
```

**XSLT 2.0** (works as 1.0 too)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|*|processing-instruction()|comment()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<Element1><attr1>test1</attr1></Element1>
```

Comment: I have tried this XSLT transformation on the output XML from Saxon processor. However, I still cannot open the resulted XML. Thank you.

Comment: @user2051823 - Why can't you open the file? Is there an error?

Answer (score 1):

The option indent="no" is the default. If you are getting indented output, then either (a) you have asked for it using indent="yes", or (b) the whitespace is present in the result tree before serialization. If the whitespace is present in the result tree, then either (b1) the stylesheet added it to the result tree, or (b2) it was copied from the source document. If (b2) is the cause, then putting `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` in your stylesheet might be the answer (assuming you don't have any significant whitespace in the source document that needs to be preserved).

We can't give anything other than general advice unless you show us your code.

Comment: I am not sure whether the problem of stylesheet or source document, but if I use other XSLT processor the line break issue doesn't exist. Here is the settings for my XSLT:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
And for the XML,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
Thank you!

Comment: If the "other XSLT processor" is using the Microsoft XML parser, then the chances are you are relying on its non-standard space-stripping behaviour - if this is the case then `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` should solve it.